# Installing graphics drivers for GeForce 8500 GT

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Using the latest Ubuntu 13.10 and trying to get the proprietary drivers for my  GeForce 8500 GT. But it doesn't show in the **Additional settings**. It's blank. Am I doing something wrong or should I download it from the Nvidia homepage? How do I install it? Step by step would be awesome for me as a non-geek.

Answer (score 1):

The nvidia-319 drivers are the ones you want.

See:
http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.32-driver.html (from the package description, visible in Synaptic)